# When email or password fields are not filled its not showing the message "Login is incorrect"

Tags: python

Im trying to do a basic login system but Im having some logic issue.

I want to show "Login is incorrect" message whenever email or password fields are not filled and also when the results dont contain an user with email and password informed.

But when the email or password fields are not filled its not showing the message "Login is incorrect"

Can you give a help to put this working correctly?

```
def login():

    while True:
        email = ""
        password = ""
        while not email or not password:
            email = raw_input("Enter your username:")
            password = raw_input('Password:')
        results = # get a row from database where email = email and password = password
        for result in results:
            if result["email"] == email and result["password"] == password:
                print "Login correct"               
                return True
            else:
                return False

def main():
    if login():
        # do something
    else:
        print "Login is incorrect"

main()
```

Comment: basic debugging: start comparing the email and password separately instead of at the same time, see which one (or if both) is different.

Answer (score 1):

```
def login():

    while True:
        email = ""
        password = ""
        while not email or not password:
            email = raw_input("Enter your username:")
            password = raw_input('Password:')
        results = # get a row from database where email = email and password = password
        for result in results:
            if result["email"] == email and result["password"] == password:
                print "Login correct"               
                return True
            else:
                print "Login incorrect" 
                return False
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But also with your solution when email or password are empty dont shows the message "Login incorrect"!

Comment: So wich message you want to show if the email or password are empty?

Answer (score 1):

the probelm is with your while in login method:

```
def login():

while True:
    email = ""
    password = ""
    while not email or not password:
        email = raw_input("Enter your username:")
        password = raw_input('Password:')
        if not email or not password:
           return False #this is the key

    results = # get a row from database where email = email and password = password
    for result in results:
        if result["email"] == email and result["password"] == password:
            print "Login correct"               
            return True
        else:
            return False

def main():
    if login():
        # do something
    else:
        print "Login is incorrect"

main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Im having the same result..when email or password are empty dont shows "Login is incorrect"

Comment: Its working, I was testing wrong, sorry! But its not working 100% correct, because when the fields are empty I want to show the message but also show again the email and password inputs so user can enter the credentials again, but I dont understand why, its not working this way!

Comment: happy to see your problem is solved ;) ! 
please mark this question as solved so that others can find the solution in future ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have a logical error in your code.

You ask your database to give you all results with a matching user and password. The result should be **exactly** one row or no rows.

If you have **one row** it must be correct. There is no need to compare username and password again because you did this in your database query.

If the database query yields **no rows** your code won't enter the for loop and so will not print anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Im using aws, and this results variable returns an boto.dynamodb.layer2.TableGenerator object. And returns this object always even when the email and password are wrong.

Comment: I never used AWS, but I wouldn't expect the TableGenerator to yield any result if no result was found.